# need help to uninstall npsp on our org

Tags: npsp, uninstall

We are facing **issues on uninstalling non profit starter pack** on our org.  I keep getting these 2 errors:

> Account.Organization.Layout and Account.Household.Layout are
>   referenced by System Administrator.

I've triple checked that this is not the case and when I try to access the profile from the error page I am told that I have insufficient privileges (I'm the Sys Admin) and when I try to view the page layouts I get:

> "You are missing information needed by the page you have attempted to
>   access. If you believe this is an error, please refresh your screen.
>   If the error persists, please report it to our Customer Support team
>   and provide the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any
>   other related information."

The **version of NPSP is Version 3.37** and all associated packages. Has anybody had this issue and if so could you tell us what the problem would be?
Buyan

Comment: You are following the steps in https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Uninstalling-the-NPSP ?

Answer (score -1):

I was reading through the documentation and seems like you have to unassign some Page Layouts before you are allowed to uninstall the whole package. There is a full guide to uninstall the package [here](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Uninstall).